# Naming convention for weakly capturing self in a closure

Tags: swift

Because this strongly captures `self`, which may have gone out of scope before the closure is executed:

```
OperationQueue().addOperation {
    self.someFunction()
}
```

... in these situations I capture `self` weakly and use a guard to check it's still in scope.

I used to write it like this:

```
OperationQueue().addOperation { [weak self] in
    guard let `self` = self else { return }

    self.someFunction()
}
```

But have since discovered that only works due to a compiler bug!
https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/007425.html

So now I use a different constant name. Reading other peoples' code the most common one I see is this:

```
OperationQueue().addOperation { [weak self] in
    guard let weakSelf = self else { return }

    weakSelf.someFunction()
}
```

But surely `self` is strong from that guard? So it should be written like this:

```
OperationQueue().addOperation { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

    strongSelf.someFunction()
}
```

**Is there a convention for the best way to write this?**

-

**UPDATE - Why optional chaining isn't optimal in this situation:**

If there are multiple calls to `self` in the closure, and `self` goes out of scope during the execution of the closure, then you may end up with unexpected state.

Also having a guard shows the next developer that this function requires `self` to work, i.e. it doesn't make sense to run the closure without `self`.

Comment: If you are using  [weak self] it means it could be nil in the closure. why don't you directly call somefunction like self?.someFunction

Comment: That’s certainly an option, but if there are more calls to `self` in the closure, it turns out easier to guard and bail out early if `self` is `nil`.

Comment: Zoul is correct. If there are multiple calls to `self`, and it goes out of scope during the closure then you may end up with unexpected state. Also having a guard shows the next developer that this function requires `self` to work, if it doesn't make sense to run the closure without `self`, it should be checked with a guard.

Comment: Why not simply optional chaining `self?.someFunction()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Swift 4.2 you can use `guard let self = self else { return }` to unwrap `weak self`. There is no need to use `strongSelf` or `` `self` `` compiler bug for unwrapping.
You can read more about it in the [Swift evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can give your object a name in capture list this way:

```
OperationQueue().addOperation { [weak object = self] in
    guard let object = object else { return }
    object.someFunction()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting feature I didn’t know about, but it doesn’t answer the question!